C# Model property values are uninitialized when private, yet work when public
My class:
public class LinkQueryOptions2
{
    private string url { get; set; }
    private bool isMobile { get; set; }
}

My API method:
[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
public void GenerateLink([FromBody] LinkQueryOptions2 data)
{
    ....
}

My fetch call in JavaScript:
const data = {
    url: "{{urlOri}}",
    isMobile: isMobile,
};

fetch("http://localhost:57266", {
    method: "POST",
    mode: "cors",
    cache: "no-cache",
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    },
    
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
});

In the backend I receive in my object the uninitialized values.
If I declare the properties of my class other than with private, it works - but I don't understand why, any ideas?
public class LinkQueryOptions2
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public bool isMobile { get; set; }
}


If the properties are private, the ModelBinder will not have access to hydrate them.

Your class attributes should be public like below:
public class LinkQueryOptions2
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public bool isMobile { get; set; }
}

Then as @Rory McCrossan said ModelBinder will be able to access the attributes accordingly.
